# View-Source + PHP ou JS

Tags: segurança

Olá, eu sou um estudante novo nesta área e gostaria de saber como eu copio o código do view-source para dentro de um textarea, é somente uma duvida para estudos e futuramente pretendo fazer um sistema de segurança a respeito ...

Exemplo: tenho o link google.com e quando aperta ctrl+u abre o link view-source:http:google.com o que eu quero é pega este código da forma que esta, pois em algumas vezes ele vem com informações do banco de dados ou ate mesmo do cookie, eu preciso pegar o código e colocar em um textarea de uma host.

eu consegui usar CUrl e ele até faz oque eu quero, mas não mostra algumas informações que o view-source mostraria como algo no cookie...

Comment: O curl mostra-te tudo acerca da requisição e resposta, em relação aos cookies este vão estar nos headers: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html. Mostra muito mais que o view source. Até consegues hackear sistemas menos seguros com curl, https://www.google.pt/search?q=hacking+com+with+com+curl&oq=hacking.com+with.com+curl&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j33.6160j0j4&client=ms-android-huawei&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8. Se fizeres `curl -v http://wwe.ex.com` vês os headers e os cookies todos, mais o corpo da resposta

Comment: eu sei,mas preciso das informações em uma pagina php dentro de um textarea

Comment: nesse caso tens de fazer um parse ao html, se este for estático tens um bom exemplo aqui http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627489/php-parse-html-code, se fores usar php

Comment: oque eu quero e realmente pega tudo oq esta no view-source e passar para um textarea em um site diferente, exemplo pego da google.com e coloco no textarea de um host meu ;) tipo exibindo o código em um textarea, eu testei com um site a pouco tempo e até q funciono o método q fiz,mas onde era pra estar uma informação que não seis e é banco de dados ou cookie, não apareceu anda, mas no view-source aparece